# comparison between MKH 60 , MKH 70 and KMR 82

Tags: location-recording

guys, i have a studio recording. i was planning to use 2 boom mics - both MKH 70 . but right now i am only getting one MKH 70..cant decide which other mic to use. i have MKH 60 and  KMR 82 as options.. could anyone plz help me suggest which one i can use. i have been told KMR 82 is more like MKH 70, though i have never used it. any suggestions would be welcome.

**its bit of urgent.plz help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KMR 82 is similar to the MKH 70 in polar axis and sensitivity. Great mic for exterior locations for blocking out noise. If you are looking at recording dialogue in studio then the mkh 50 with the 60 is a good match. But that depends on the room. If you are doing ADR, maybe try to use the mic that was used on set to record in studio to match as much of the quality from the quide track. I have seen the KMR also used in in live recording situations on stage to capture instruments without the room being an issue.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Hi, don't know the kmr 82, but own and use the mkh60. Should be a good match with the 70.
But if it's a studio recording, why do you need a super long shotgun? Is it impossible to get close to the actors? I'd use a mkh50 in an indoors situation, unless it has enormous reverberations then I would use the 60.

Arnoud

Answer (score 0):

What are you recording - dialogue? Like Arnoud mentioned above, the mkh-70 is a super long shotgun. I usually only use it only in super noisy exteriors, with a well seasoned boom operator who knows how and where to point the mic. Otherwise if you're even slightly off-axis your sound will be heavily colored, not in the way you want.

You're not needing to so a stereo recording, are you?

The MKH 60 is a fantastic mic, and ditto, will match the 70 well if those are your only options. Not familiar kmr82 either.

Answer (score 0):

Hi :)

I've got the KMR 82, very good mic to capture sound in documentary and movies (in outdoor, when the source is far),it should be avoided in a reverberated environment. 
It is heavy to carry to a boompole.

I use it also for record all kind of sound effects.

Unfortunately, I haven't try other mics to make a comparison ...
In all cases, these are all good mics and they can last a very long time (for example mine has over 15 years).